# How to edit this Top N in Tableau to be based on a conditional

Tags: tableau-desktop

I have the following Top N set in Tableau. I would like to edit it so that its also based on if a field I have, [Fund] = XX. I've been running into trouble trying to build this. If I bring in the Fund field into my filter then filter, it only shows the deals remaining in the top 10.

[image]

Comment: have you tried using the formula editor box just below?

Comment: Yes but I’m not sure how to structure it to have it work. It says I can’t add a conditional that ties to that field

Comment: Can you share your work via Tableau Public? https://public.tableau.com/app/profile/debayan.kar